# Python: Tkinter Only fires Event after Closing Window

Tags: python, callback, tkinter

Take this example I found on http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm:

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback():
    print "clicked!"

b = Button(text="click me", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

When the window pops up and I click the button, nothing happens.

However, when I close this window, the phrase "clicked!" appears as many times as I clicked the button prior to closing the window.

Is this normal behavior? I'm trying to figure this out, because I have another Tkinter GUI I'm working on exhibiting the exact same behavior, and I need to know if its something internal to the code, or something external in the machine.

**EDIT : Something with my Sublime build seems to be the issue, command line fixes the stdout issue.**

Comment: I just ran the code on my Ubuntu machine both in an interactive session and from a file, using Python 2.7.5 *and* 3.3.2 and everything worked as expected. What OS and Python version are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 with a Python Version of 2.7.5.

The strangest thing though, it might be Sublime Text,

I just re-ran the file from cmd line and it isnt blocking stdout. I'll do a quick check of my Sublime Build system

Comment: Just ran the same code again with my Sublime Text 3 using the build-system with no issues. I haven't changed any build settings or even used that system, so it's definitely not a general sublime issue.